# Using an artistic developer name for App Store instead of my real name

Tags: iphone, app-store, iphone-developer-program

I'm going to enroll in the Apple Developer Program as an individual developer and most likely will need to tell Apple my actual name in the process (do I really have to?). And what I'm wondering about is:

Will there be a way for me to tell App Store to display my artistic name (an alias) instead of my real name when a customer visits the page of any of my apps?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They just changed their policies... apparently it will show your real name now... :( but hopefully they will grandfather past accounts... Otherwise it will make it unaffordable for small outfits to sell under a company name without incorporating. (and of course by our customers paying ~$1 per app, they have the right to know our legal names so they can track us down and call our mobile numbers and ask stupid questions!)

See below email from apple support received a few days ago:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Program Support regarding the
>   iOS Developer Program.
>
> My name is Maritza and I will be happy to assist you with your
>   inquires redrawing your wife enrolling under a new account.
>
> Developers enrolled in the iOS Developer Program are no longer able to
>   set an Artist name in iTunes Connect. The artist name now defaults to
>   the individuals legal name as it appears on the membership. This means
>   you would not be able to set your artist name as "You Company Name", instead your name would show in the App Store. I
>   apologize for any inconvenience this may cause.
>
> I hope you find this information useful. If you have any
>   questions or need further assistance, please contact us Monday through
>   Friday from 7:00 a.m. to 5:00 p.m. (PST) at 800-633-2152. We're happy
>   to help.
>
> Regards,
>
> Maritza
>
> Apple Developer Program Support

If you live in the states, set up an individual LLC. It's pretty cheap ($150 or so) and you can do it online. It will also let you use your company name instead of your full name.

Answer (score 3):

Choose carefully, as it is not easy (or even possible) to change later without buying a new Developer account.  None of your apps are transferrable.

If you don't want to use your name, you can use a company name, however you'll probably need the relevant business credentials to back it up.

**Edit**: this was originally written at a time when it was not possible to transfer apps. It is now pretty easy to transfer an app to another entity. The only caveat is if you use certain features like CloudKit, your app may be unable to be transferred.

Comment: Apps are transferable.

Comment: This was a pretty old answer and was correct at the time... but I updated the answer with a clarification.

Comment: Thanks about 'transferable' update. I will use my personal then transfer to new company's developer account once it has relevant business credentials. It's possible, right? Can we change the app developer info on transferring?

Answer (score 2):

I am just looking into the same process. I am a sole trader and wish to put app out under a company name. The information i just received from speaking with an Apple support staff is that to do this you have to register as a "company" (not an "individual") and then you will get a one-off opportunity to enter a company name, aka "artist name" (which can be anything), as it is separate to your legal entity name/actual company name.

The easiest/cheapest way to do this, is to change from a sole trader to a partnership, and then register as a company. (well that's in Australia anyway!)

link to apple info here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/2_BeforeYouBegin/BeforeYouBegin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH11-SW1

good luck!

Viv

Comment: Viv, when you say, 'change from a sole trader to a partnership, and then register as a company' (in Australia), do you mean you have to register your business as an actual company with ASIC, or do you mean Apple will accept a 'company' registration if your business is a registered partnership? I assume the latter, but I just wanted to make sure. Can you verify that this worked, and that Apple let you use your partnership's trading name rather than your individual names? This would be very good news, as a partnership structure is indeed a lot simpler and cheaper to maintain than a company.

Comment: I suspect this answer, as it relates to Australian partnerships, is wrong. Apple use D-U-N-S numbers to verify an organisation's legal entity status (https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/). So it occurred to me that I could search Dun & Bradstreet's database for Australian partnerships. Unfortunately, partnerships are listed with the names of both partners, not the registered business name. I found just one exception, where a partnership was listed under its business name, so I suspect this was some kind of data-entry error. Lucky for them I suppose if they want to be on the App Store!

Answer (score 1):

There are two names visible in the App Store:

You can choose whatever you want as your Developer Name when you submit your first app. Once you set it, you cannot change it. This would be the "artistic name" you describe.

However, the App Store/iTunes will always display your real name as *seller name* (in small type), which is the legal entity that produced the app. Buyers have a right to know this information.

If you don't want your real name on the App Store in any form, you must create a corporate entity and open a developer account on its behalf. However, if you just want a nicer name for marketing purposes, you can do that as an individual.

Comment: They just changed their policies... apparently it will show your real name now... :(

Comment: @swinefeaster If that's true you should post a new answer and link to a source if possible.

Comment: Ok, see new answer below. I don't agree that "Buyers have a right to know this information". Since when does buying a $1 app or getting one for free give you the right to someone's private name? Incorporating just for privacy is impractical for small outfits. Apple needs to get slapped.

Comment: @swinefeaster Since before computers... if you operate a business under a "fictitious name" most states (in U.S.) require you to have a real name and contact information on file so that a customer can find out who is behind a business. And, if someone wants to run executable code on my phone, with access to my private information, I think I ought to have to right to know their identity. I understand incorporating is a pain, but if obscuring your real name from the people you want to sell to is important, it's not a huge burden.

Comment: It is a huge burden actually. 1k to incorporate and then an extra $600 or so a year to file taxes, and that's not counting bank fees for having a company bank account and yearly "meetings with yourself". I've been there, and for a hobby project it really is a burden. Consider also that when you deal with a company, you don't really know who you are dealing with - apple support staff don't provide their full names. Hypocrisy I say.

Comment: @swinefeaster 1. I've done it and it didn't cost nearly that much. 2. Nobody is forcing you sell software. 3. Stack Overflow isn't really the place for a debate but if you'd like to continue the conversation, see my profile for how to contact me.